# Do I need to use Azure AD B2B or B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2b

we are building an application (Azure website) where we want people to be able to log in with local accounts (created in Azure) but also with their Office365 account. Of course, it would be great if we could add Google Workspace etc. to enable SSO.

What we like about Azure AD B2C is that you can set up your own login flows for login, password reset etc. I don’t think the same thing seems to exist in Azure AD B2B.

So should we use Azure AD B2B or B2C or B2B with External Identities?

**Our requirements:**

- Support for local logins
- Support for Microsoft work accounts (Office365)"
- I hope this helps! Let me know if you have any other questions
- Use login flow if possible (only B2C?)

So not sure if I should go for B2B or B2C (default only MS personal accounts).

I think it’s really hard to figure out the difference between B2B and B2C (of course by the name it should be against business/consumers).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/what-is-b2b
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview

Answer (score 2):

Agree it's confusing, especially as [Entra External ID](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/business/identity-access/microsoft-entra-external-id) (CIAM) is in the mix.

You could use B2C and set up O365 as an [external IDP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-identity-provider).

Then you could log in with local B2C accounts, O365 accounts and any other OIDC-based / SAML accounts.

Comment: Yup, that was my thought too, but it seems like there are so many steps just to set up O365 when there’s an out-of-the-box solution for Azure AD. I also looked at this video and after that I was thinking maybe Azure AD is the way to go and use external identities. It is just business users we will have in our AD, not private persons.

But I really like the user flow in B2C ;)

Good video for some more understanding
https://youtu.be/9P10hgPDRZg

Comment: Microsoft 365 is more of a B2B thing, But your question mentioned "Support for Microsoft work accounts" so if you mean a corporate account e.g. joe.bloggs@company.co.nz then B2C can handle that.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the CIAM preview, where Microsoft is integrating B2C with B2B:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/microsoft-entra-external-id-public-preview-developer-centric/ba-p/3823766

This will solve the choice between B2B and B2C in the future, however it currently still needs a separate tenant